# If double derivative test fails can we go for Higher derivatives

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

if $f(x)=x^4$ we have critical points given by $$4x^3=0$$ which is $x=0$

Now $$f''(x)=12x^2$$ so $$f''(0)=0$$ and also $x=0$ is not Point of Inflexion since $f''(0^{+})$ and $f''(0^{-})$ have same sign. Now if we take triple derivative $$f'''(x)=24x$$ and $$f''''(0) \gt 0$$

Can we say $x=0$ is Local Minima because from graph of $x^4$,Minima occurs at $x=0$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a general form of the derivative test.
Roughly it is as follows.

Let $c$ be a point such that the first $n$ derivatives are zero and the $n+1$th derivative is nonzero. If $n$ is odd, then

if $f^{(n+1)}(c) < 0 $, then $c$ is a local maximum

if $f^{(n+1)}(c) > 0 $, then $c$ is a local minimum

See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test) for a more precise and complete answer.

Comment: ok where can i get proof for this

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020984/why-does-the-higher-order-derivative-test-work for a neat answer.